Hint for solving the limit $ \lim _{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\left|x\right|\log\left|x\right|}{\sqrt{\left|x\right|}+\sqrt{\left|y\right|}}$
Can anyone help me with a hint on how to solve this limit?
$$\lim _{\left(x,\ y\right)\to \left(0,\:0\right)}\frac{\left|x\right|\log \left|x\right|}{\sqrt{\left|x\right|}+\sqrt{\left|y\right|}}$$
I started trying to prove it by paths, but all the limits go to zero. Later, I tried polar coordinates but even using L'Hopital several times I can't get out of indetermination. I also can't think of an inequality to try to use the Squeeze theorem.

You can actually remove all mod signs and compute the limit at $0^{+}$

Hint: its modulus is bound by $\sqrt{|x|}\ln|x|$, which $\to0$ as $x\to0$. Now use the squeeze theorem.

The denominator is going to $0$ the numerator is also going to $0$...now apply l hopital's rule ....do partial differentiation wrt x

The limit is not well defined as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ means that $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ It should be written $\lim_{x\to 0,y\to 0}$

@RyszardSzwarc I've seen often and I always use the notation $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ meaning $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to 0$.

@user I use the same meaning. Hence $(0,y)$ $y\neq $ is possible, but the function is not well defined at such points because of the presence of $\ln|x|.$

@RyszardSzwarc In this case I always assume, by definition, this points not included in the domain.

@RyszardSzwarc I see now that I have considered wrongly this case in the alternative solution. Thanks

As suggested in the comments, since $\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}\ge \sqrt{|x|}$
$$\left|
\frac{|x|\log|x|}{\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}}
\right|\le 
\left|
\frac{|x|\log|x|}{\sqrt{|x|}}
\right|
=
\sqrt{|x|}\left|\log|x|\right|
$$
Can you conclude from here?

As an alternative, by polar coordinates
$$\frac{|x|\log|x|}{\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}}= \frac{\sqrt \rho |\cos \theta|\left(\log \rho+\log|\cos \theta|\right)}{\sqrt{|\cos \theta|}+\sqrt{|\sin \theta|}}\to 0$$
indeed $\sqrt{|\cos \theta|}+\sqrt{|\sin \theta|} \ge \cos^2 \theta+\sin^2 \theta=1$ and
$$\sqrt \rho |\cos \theta|\left(\log \rho+\log|\cos \theta|\right)= \sqrt \rho \log \rho|\cos \theta|+\sqrt \rho|\cos \theta|\log|\cos \theta|\to 0 + 0 =0$$
since $|\cos \theta|\log|\cos \theta|$ is bounded.

Yes, thank you bro!

@AnneBauval Yes of course! I fix that. Thanks

@AnneBauval First way seems really more effective in this case! I hope the second one is fine now! Thanks for the great help.

Indeed. This "alternative" is correct now but really not worth.

@AnneBauval I think very it is instructive though!

$\sqrt{|\cos \theta|}+\sqrt{|\sin \theta|}\geq1.$

@Riemann Yes indeed $\sqrt{|\cos \theta|}+\sqrt{|\sin \theta|} \ge \cos^2 \theta+\sin^2 \theta=1$. I add that too. Thanks

Actually, $$1\leq\sqrt[n]{|\cos \theta|}+\sqrt[n]{|\sin \theta|}\leq2^{\frac{2n-1}{2n}},\quad \forall n\geq2.$$

@user
You give a nice answer!

@Riemann With a lot of credits to Anne Bauval, I must say! Thanks
